# Javascript - Get window.selection() range of a condenteditable paragraph with spans accounted inside the end length

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

When I selected the paragraph text which has no styles it works fine, I get the start and end of the range. But, if I have a span with some styling inside the paragraph text, the end of the range is wrong.

start: 0, end: 23 *OK*

[image: works]

---

"common" is now a span with font-weight: bold style!

start: 0, end: 7

*Which is wrong, the end should still be 23*
[image]

---

```js
handleMouseUp(event) {
  const selection = window.getSelection()

  const start = selection.anchorOffset
  const end = selection.focusOffset

  if (start >= 0 && end >= 0) {
    this.curSelection = {
      start, end
    }
  }
}
```

Here is also a live Sandbox. I use Vue.js so it's different and I don't know how to make an example in raw JS, but the function handleMouseUp and the code inside it is all that matters:

[Live Code example that can be adjusted](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-river-9bg9mt?file=/src/App.vue)

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by getting the selected text length and setting end = start + selTextLength:

```
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
  const selTextLength = selectedText.length

  const start = selection.anchorOffset
  const end = start + selTextLength
```